Tool to extract functions used from specific package in Python
Does anyone know a tool to copy all the functions used in a project comming from a specific package? A possible use case would be something like the following:
Project A is a Python application that uses several functions from Package B as a dependency. Let's say that Package B is a private project, if we distribute Project A together with all its dependencies this will include all the code from Package B, even all the functions not used in Project A.
Is there any automatic way to find every function from Package B that's used in Project A so that it can be copied using the same module structure? That way just by changing imports from from package_b import A, B, C we could just use from project_a import A, B, C.
I understand that due to Python dynamic nature the general case could be quite complicated, but I would be happy with a tool that recives as an input one or more package names like "package_b", then identifies imports "from package_b.* import x, y, z" and then copies over the code for functions "x", "y" and "z".

You may be able to script this. I'd check out this SO answer as it may be a useful resource.

You could just read the python files and check for imports from project_b
from pathlib import Path

d = Path('dir/of/project_a')
for pyfile in d.glob('**/*.py'):
    for i, line in enumerate(pyfile, 1):
        if "import project_b" in line or "from project_b" in line:
            print(f'[{i:>3}]{pyfile}: {line}')

